# Display Parent Category

Tags: categories

EE3

Is it possible to display the parent category of the current entry?

```
    {exp:channel:entries
        channel="news"
        disable="member_data|pagination|trackbacks"
        dynamic="no"
        limit="7"
        category="24|26"}

    {categories}
            {parents}
                    {parents:title}
            {/parents}
    {/categories}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes of course, you should use [GW Code Categories](http://gwcode.com/).
After installing that plugin, please try below code. I think it will work to get parent category.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="channel_name" disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks|relationships" dynamic="no"}
    {exp:gwcode_categories entry_id="{entry_id}" style="linear" depth="1"}
        {cat_name}<br>
    {/exp:gwcode_categories}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: GW code categories is not available in EE3 but you can make it compatible by just adding addon.setup.php file.

Comment: Thank you both, I adjusted GW Code Categories to work with EE3 and it does just what I wanted!

Answer (score -1):

You just need to specify which field from your news channel you want to do the looking up from.  See this very clear example in the [EE3 documentation](https://docs.expressionengine.com/v3/fieldtypes/relationships.html#accessing-parents).

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="childChannel"}
  {parents field="relationship_field"}
    {parents:title} - {parents:field1} - {parents:field2}
  {/parents}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: I think he ask for categories not relationships